# I accidentally gave out my name, home address, email address, phone number, and my DOB

Tags: identity-theft

Will anything go wrong??? I'm so scared...
I can't even sleep anymore..
It was a phone call telling me about some kind of benefit
I gave out my name, address, phone number, DOB, and email address and nothing else
Will I be OK??? 
I'm so scared help me

Comment: I voted that this is a duplicate of the question @yoozer8 noted. You've also given our your DOB, but that's also often available from various sources. It would be irresponsible give blanket reassurance, but chances are that you'll mostly get lots of spam through various channels. But it's like a combination lock - you've disclosed the equivalent of 1 or 2 of 3 digits. You should be very careful with the rest of your private information.

Comment: Will that be all?? Just getting more spam??

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine. That's all information that's publicly available (even if you have to put a bit of effort into it).

Chances are you are going to see  more spam (phone and e-mail) and more scam & phishing attempts, since you are now a more attractive target (since you already fell for it). If you are diligent and pay attention, that should be okay. Don't talk or communicate with people unless you initiate the conversation yourself or you know them. Never sent or receive money from strangers on the internet.

It's probably a good idea to check your bank and credit card accounts regularly for any type of suspicious activity and to check your credit reports (which you can do for free once a year)

Comment: Big, huge emphasis on the last paragraph. A "partial" leak like this might not be a problem in isolation, but the thing is - you don't know if this particular scammer *already* had some other info on you, or will obtain it in the future. If you're not already in the habit of looking at your accounts and credit report regularly, take the 5 minutes to check for issues a few times a week for the next 6 months.